# Magento 2.1 : Multiple Image Uploader in Ui Component Form

Tags: magento-2.1, template, grid, uicomponent, image-upload

I am getting this error

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="add-video-button-container">
        <button id="add_video_button"
                title="Add Video"
                data-role="add-video-button"
                type="button"
                class="action-secondary"
                data-ui-id="widget-button-1">
            <span>Add Video</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="media_gallery_content"
     class="gallery"
     data-mage-init='{"openVideoModal":{}}'
     data-parent-component="name_form.name_form.block_gallery.block_gallery"
     data-images="<br />
```

> **Fatal error**:  Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null
>   in
>   **/opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento-CE-2.1.2_sample/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php** on line **0**
>  I want to add Magento's default **multiple**
>   image **uploader** in my project.

In layout I have referenced the uploader to my form in the following way.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="name_form"/>
        <referenceContainer name="name_form">
        <block name="gallery" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gallery Images</item>
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                    <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Xyz\Edit\Tab\Image" as="content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">name_form.name_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>

            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

And the Content file in Block is:

```
    namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Media\Helper\Form\Gallery;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Content extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'media/helper/gallery.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config
     */
    protected $_mediaConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $_jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $mediaConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $mediaConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->_mediaConfig = $mediaConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->addChild('uploader', 'Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader');

        $this->getUploader()->getConfig()->setUrl(
            $this->_urlBuilder->addSessionParam()->getUrl('frontname/media/upload')
        )->setFileField(
            'image'
        )->setFilters(
            [
                'images' => [
                    'label' => __('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                    'files' => ['*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png'],
                ],
            ]
        );

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout', ['block' => $this]);

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve uploader block
     *
     * @return Uploader
     */
    public function getUploader()
    {
        return $this->getChildBlock('uploader');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve uploader block html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUploaderHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('uploader');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsObjectName()
    {
        return $this->getHtmlId() . 'JsObject';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddImagesButton()
    {
        return $this->getButtonHtml(
            __('Add New Images'),
            $this->getJsObjectName() . '.showUploader()',
            'add',
            $this->getHtmlId() . '_add_images_button'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImagesJson()
    {
        $value = $this->getElement()->getImages();
        if (is_array($value) &&
            array_key_exists('images', $value) &&
            is_array($value['images']) &&
            count($value['images'])
        ) {
            $directory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $images = $this->sortImagesByPosition($value['images']);
            foreach ($images as &$image) {
                $image['url'] = $this->_mediaConfig->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
                $fileHandler = $directory->stat($this->_mediaConfig->getMediaPath($image['file']));
                $image['size'] = $fileHandler['size'];
            }
            return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($images);
        }
        return '[]';
    }

    /**
     * Sort images array by position key
     *
     * @param array $images
     * @return array
     */
    private function sortImagesByPosition($images)
    {
        if (is_array($images)) {
            usort($images, function ($imageA, $imageB) {
                return ($imageA['position'] < $imageB['position']) ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }
        return $images;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImagesValuesJson()
    {
        $values = [];
        foreach ($this->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute */
            $values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $this->getElement()->getDataObject()->getData(
                $attribute->getAttributeCode()
            );
        }
        return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($values);
    }

    /**
     * Get image types data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getImageTypes()
    {
        $imageTypes = [];
        foreach ($this->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute */
            $imageTypes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                'value' => $this->getElement()->getDataObject()->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()),
                'label' => $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
                'scope' => __($this->getElement()->getScopeLabel($attribute)),
                'name' => $this->getElement()->getAttributeFieldName($attribute),
            ];
        }
        return $imageTypes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve default state allowance
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasUseDefault()
    {
        foreach ($this->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if ($this->getElement()->canDisplayUseDefault($attribute)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve media attributes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMediaAttributes()
    {
        return $this->getElement()->getDataObject()->getMediaAttributes();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve JSON data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageTypesJson()
    {
        return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($this->getImageTypes());
    }
}
```

Can any one figure it out , or had a working sample to tally.

Comment: Thanks @Vishwas Bhatnagar for the edits . It looks better now

Comment: hi @Verdu I am also trying to get multi image uploader like product form. If you achieve this please help me! My question here: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312434/how-to-create-multi-image-uploader-in-custom-ui-component-form